# Map X-values to a Date in d3.time.scale()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 chart that draws out a number of rectangles over an x-axis.

The x-axis represents a timeline and I currently use d3.time.scale in order to map the dates of each datapoint to a point on the x-axis. This is all straight forward.

```
var xAxis = d3.time.scale();
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.xValue = xAxis(d.startDate);
});
```

Then drawing it out using that specific xValue in a css `transform`.

Now, if I would like to get the date based on a given x-value (say for instance when a user clicks on the graph I want to check which date that x-value corresponds to) I have not found how to do this using the `xAxis` variable that I have created.

How can I achieve this? Would I have to use the `xAxis.domain()` and the `width` of the element to calculate the chosen date?

Comment: [`aAxis.invert()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#invert) -- the variable name is really misleading BTW. I would call it `xScale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the answer from Lars Kotthoff in the comments;

[`d3.time.scale().invert()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#invert) was the answer to this.